# C# Security Credentials to a SOAP Message ERROR - WS-Security (WSS)

Tags: c#, web-services, soap

I am trying to call a method on a WebReference (web-service) client that must use WS-Security. When i execute the cargaFicheiro method it returns the following error:

> An invalid security token was provided (An error happened processing
>   a Username Token).

The code i'm using is:

```
// Cuidamos is a WebReference do a WSDL url in https

var token = new UsernameToken("Username", "Password", PasswordOption.SendPlainText);

var serviceProxy = new Cuidamos.CargaFicheiroServiceImplService();

SoapContext requestContext = serviceProxy.RequestSoapContext;
requestContext.Security.Timestamp.TtlInSeconds = 300;
requestContext.Security.Tokens.Add(token);

var result = serviceProxy.cargaFicheiro();
```

The SOAP header must match this one:

```
<soap:Header>
    <wsse:Security xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" soap:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="TS-2">
            <wsu:Created>2013-10-07T10:13:52Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2013-10-07T10:20:32Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-1">
            <wsse:Username>USERNAME</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">PASSWORD</wsse:Password>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soap:Header>
```

I have used the following answer to implement my code:
https://stackoverflow.com/a/40030906/2449703

Based on Microsoft i am doing all in the right way:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/dotnet/netframework-1.1/ms819938(v=msdn.10)

Again other answer that works, but not in my case:
[https://forums.asp.net/t/2133187.aspx?C+oasis+Username+token](https://forums.asp.net/t/2133187.aspx?C%20oasis%20Username%20token1.1/ms819938(v=msdn.10))

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

WSSE Nonce is a security attribute with a unique identifier designed to prevent replay attacks. Your server is likely generating this because you have a custom service binding configured in your service config.

It should work exactly once,which is likely why you can't re-use it from SOAPUI

More info here:

https://weblog.west-wind.com/posts/2012/nov/24/wcf-wssecurity-and-wse-nonce-authentication

Comment: But if the soap request is going through https do i need this nonce? I do not have any custom service binding.

Comment: The document provided by the team that manages this service doesn't reference the Nonce element in the Soap Header, so i am assuming that is not required.

Comment: I also have tried to generate a different Nonce phrase and use it in Soap UI and it returns the same error. I have used GetSHA1String(phrase) method from west-wind blog that you posted.

Comment: What does Cuidamos.CargaFicheiroServiceImplService() do?

Comment: It will generate a proxy from a Service Reference (not Web Reference), legacy btw. Don't know if i answer your question.

Answer (score 0):

My question is almost solved.

I have notice that the SOAP Header generated by this code is the following:

```
<soapenv:Header>
    <wsa:Action></wsa:Action>
    <wsa:MessageID>uuid:2eead708-03f9-4624-a866-35f3730eac23</wsa:MessageID>
    <wsa:ReplyTo>
        <wsa:Address>http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/03/addressing/role/anonymous</wsa:Address>
    </wsa:ReplyTo>
    <wsa:To>https://cuidamos.com/ws/cuidamos</wsa:To>
    <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1">
        <wsu:Timestamp wsu:Id="Timestamp-64f67137-f82d-4a9c-8b2e-1cc41104683d">
            <wsu:Created>2019-06-27T12:48:00Z</wsu:Created>
            <wsu:Expires>2019-06-27T12:53:00Z</wsu:Expires>
        </wsu:Timestamp>
        <wsse:UsernameToken xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" wsu:Id="SecurityToken-b8467c25-c62c-406a-9831-46e6c676153a">
            <wsse:Username>Username</wsse:Username>
            <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">Password</wsse:Password>
            <wsse:Nonce>JEmovy7RDpapzumPTiUUgQ==</wsse:Nonce>
            <wsu:Created>2019-06-27T12:48:00Z</wsu:Created>
        </wsse:UsernameToken>
    </wsse:Security>
</soapenv:Header>
```

And i have used [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/428223/2449703) solution to trace my request soap message.

But when i use SoapUI application to make a request with this SOAP Header, i have notice that if i remove <wsse:Nonce> element it will work just fine. So i need to remove this <wsse:Nonce> element that is being dynamically generated and this is where i am working on, but don't know hot do it yet.

**EDIT**

I'm almost there, i have found that if i create the attribute EncodingType inside Nonce element it works, i don't need to remove Nonce element. This has been tested on SoapUI.

The Nonce element should be created like this, the innerText on Nonce element is a hash string (SHA-1) created on each request:

> <wsse:Nonce
>   EncodingType="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary">6OX8gvIRETEbzaCwZ4byn/NEpzDI=</wsse:Nonce>

To achive this result i have created dynamically UsernameToken with XML:

```
XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
XmlElement usernameTokenElement = document.CreateElement("wsse", "UsernameToken", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");

XmlElement usernameChild;
usernameChild = document.CreateElement("wsse", "Username", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
usernameChild.InnerText = "WSMASSIT";
usernameTokenElement.AppendChild(usernameChild);

XmlElement passwordChild;
passwordChild = document.CreateElement("wsse", "Password", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
passwordChild.SetAttribute("Type", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText");
passwordChild.InnerText = "AstWs218";
usernameTokenElement.AppendChild(passwordChild);

string phrase = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
var nonce = GetSHA1String(phrase); // User Function to create SHA-1 Hash String

XmlElement nonceChild;
nonceChild = document.CreateElement("wsse", "Nonce", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd");
nonceChild.SetAttribute("EncodingType", "http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-soap-message-security-1.0#Base64Binary");
nonceChild.InnerText = nonce;
usernameTokenElement.AppendChild(nonceChild);

var token = new UsernameToken(usernameTokenElement);
```

Now i have other problem, the Username and Password childs are created with success, but Nonce child is rewritten on runtime, wich means that Username and Password are created exactly as i coded but Nonce continues to be created without EncondingType and the innerText hash string is different from what my code created.

**EDIT 2**

I have done a simple test, by adding the following code

```
document.AppendChild(usernameTokenElement);

var xml = token.GetXml(document);
```

And if i inspect document i can see Nonce element with EncodingType attribute, but if i inspect xml it doesn't have EncodingType attribute on Nonce element.

**EDIT 3**

Problem solved, but question of EDIT 2 not answered.
In a nutshell Nonce is no longer required, the department responsible for managing this endpoint has done that configuration on server.
In the specification of UsernameToken WSS [document](http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0.pdf) its written that Nonce and Created are not required, so by this assumption the problem was solved that way, remembering that this request is made on a https (SSL Tunneling).